# Notification center doesn't call the selector method help me out

Tags: ios, xcode, selector, nsnotificationcenter

```
- (IBAction)playOrPauseSound:(id)sender;
{ 
    [_audioPlayer play];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:_audioPlayer selector:@selector(nextsong:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
}

- (IBAction)nextsong:(id)sender {
    //code 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the notificationObserver to `self` as this is the object which is acting as the observer. You should also set the notificationSender to `_audioPlayer` as this is the object which sends the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` notification.

Also, the selector method should have an instance of NSNotification as the only argument. So I would be tempted to create a separate method to handle receiving notifications which then calls the next song method, maybe:

```
- (void)receivedNextSongNotification:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    [self nextsong:nil];
}
```

So in its entirety, something like this:

```
- (IBAction)playOrPauseSound:(id)sender
{ 
    [_audioPlayer play]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self //will look for the selector in the current class
                                             selector: @selector(playerItemDidPlayToEndTime:) 
                                                 name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification 
                                               object: _audioPlayer]; // the object that sends the notifications
}

- (void)playerItemDidPlayToEndTime:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    [self nextsong:nil];
}

- (IBAction)nextsong:(id)sender 
{
    //code  
}
```

Also be sure to call `removeObserver:name:object:` before `self` or `_audioPlayer` is deallocated.

Hope that helps.